# Simple Webhook code 'shardCount' on string error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I trying to make and start learning to code a bid with API's But I have this really annoying error... My code is

```
    const Discord = require('discord.js')
    const webhookID = '888151030620106792'; 
    const webhookToken = 'token-here';
    
    
    const webhook = new Discord.WebhookClient(webhookID, webhookToken);



    webhook.send('I am here')
```

And The error i get out if it is:

```
PS C:\Users\jonat\Desktop\Api Dev\Discord and Rest Api> node webhooks.js
C:\Users\jonat\Desktop\Api Dev\Discord and Rest Api\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:336
        given[key] = def[key];
                   ^

TypeError: Cannot create property 'shardCount' on string 'zFutoKYe-OfZrfPdh0UE5yCk2wMOe-B84Xcs_Af6a76DXTx6bt3WB48qZwH-KvUriqtI'

    at Function.mergeDefault (C:\Users\jonat\Desktop\Api Dev\Discord and Rest Api\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:336:20)
    at new BaseClient (C:\Users\jonat\Desktop\Api Dev\Discord and Rest Api\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\BaseClient.js:20:25)
    at new WebhookClient (C:\Users\jonat\Desktop\Api Dev\Discord and Rest Api\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\WebhookClient.js:26:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jonat\Desktop\Api Dev\Discord and Rest Api\webhooks.js:9:25)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)     
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
```

I Get the same error when I do this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const webhook = new WebhookClient('888151030620106792', 'zFutoKYe-OfZrfPdh0UE5yCk2wMOe-B84Xcs_Af6a76DXTx6bt3WB48qZwH-KvUriqtI')

  
webhook.send('Hello World;)')`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const data = {
    id: 'idhere',
    token: 'tokenhere'
}
const webhook = new discord.WebhookClient(data);
webhook.send('hello');
```

I was having this issue as well today but by sending the webhook data as an object worked for me, hope this helps